# System.TypeInitializationException when creating a new SQLiteConnection in VS2019

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

When I run a debug session in Visual Studio I get a `TypeInitializerException` on when I create a new instance of the `SqLiteConnection` object.

```cs
private const string MYSECONDMOBILEAPPDB = "MySecondMobileAppDb.db3";
var databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), MYSECONDMOBILEAPPDB);

SQLiteConnection Db = new SQLiteConnection(databasePath);
```

I received this unhandled Exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception. occurred

In VS2017 my project run without any problem.

Comment: have you cleaned up everything (bin/obj) etc. The folders/caches are not compatible so you can en up in a weird state.

Comment: The exception doesn't happen after I did a clean solution and a rebuild. But after the app is started in the emulator it runs for a few seconds. After that my debug session was stopped. When I use my app in the emulator without a debug session it runs without any problem.